# For a number of vectors in $\mathbb R^{n}$ show that a particular set is a subspace of $\mathbb R^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n,m \ge 1$ and let $v_{1},\ldots,v_{m} \in \mathbb R^{n}$. Use the subspace test (for $x,y$ in the subspace, $x+y$ is also in the subspace and for $\lambda$ in the field, $\lambda \cdot x$ is also in the subspace) to show $A=\{v \in \mathbb R^n | v_{i} \circ v = 0, i = 1,\ldots m \}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^{n}$.

I really have no idea what this question is asking. I am unsure what it meant by $v_{i} \circ v$ and generally I have no idea what to do here. Could someone clarify what this question is asking and help me get started?

Thanks! Helen

Comment: $\circ$ is probably the dot product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\text{If } v,w \in A \to v_i\cdot v=0, v_i\cdot w =0\to v_i\cdot(v+w) = v_i\cdot v+v_i\cdot w = 0+0 = 0, v_i\cdot (rv) = r(v_i\cdot v) = r(0) = 0 \to A \text{ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$}$

Comment: Is this all that is required for the proof? Well, that was a lot simpler than I thought! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, Helen.